# Specific font not showing on Google Chrome but Safari can

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, safari

I noticed I couldn't find the **magnifier icon** in computed panel of Chrome inspector at the day before yesterfay. Everything looks fine before that and fonts also can display on the browser normally.
What's going on with Google Chrome?

> On chrome
>   [image: chrome]
>
> On safari
>   [image: safari]

Same css code but they are displayed with different fonts, one is **"lanting hei"** (on safari, right one), another is **"Helvetica neue"**(on chorme, wrong one)

Comment: Without seeing any code, I can only guess it's line 37

Comment: Sorry about it. I use bootstrap.css, and in my own style.css I have body{font-family: 'lanting hei';}, but it is strikeout in chrome browser and use the default font in bootstrap.css while it's normal on safari browser.

Comment: is this a font natively on the computer you are browsing with?

Comment: try getting rid of the quotes, i.e. `body{font-family: lanting hei;}` ... and if that works, please tell me it's on line 37 of style.css :p

Comment: have you tried to jiggle with it?

Comment: for some reason your font is being overrided by bootstrap on chrome... is your styles being inserted after bootstrap? you can try and make that !important so it won't get overrided or change the quotes to double quotes on the font-family

Comment: @JaromandaX Thx a lot!!! It works~~~ Yes, it is my computer native font. I want to why the problem is the quotes? :> (sorry I don't understand what is the "line 37 of style.css". You mean my code of line 37?)

Comment: don't worry, my initial response was that the problem is on line 37 - that was just a joke. I thought it would be funny if that piece of CSS appeared on line 37 in your css file :D

Comment: @Shakawkaw My style.css is inserted after the bootstrap.css.

Comment: @JaromandaX :D Thank you~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have this in your css

```
body{font-family: 'lanting hei';}
```

The font name the browser is looking for is `'lanting hei'` instead of `lanting hei` (the difference being the quotes)

Change the css to

```
body{font-family: lanting hei;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not including ttf and woff font files. Try as described below-

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'your-font-name';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("/css/fonts/your-font-name.woff") format("woff");
 }
```

or you share your code first.

Comment: `font-family: 'your-font-name';` ... ironically, putting quotes in the font name was the source of the issue

Comment: `font-family: 'your-font-name'; ` ...this never create problem..it works fine with me.

Comment: and yet, removing the quotes **did** fix the issue the OP was having ... what browser do you test on? I don't see the issue myself either